# Javascript code not working and carrying value to another section of code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, javascript-objects

The first section of my code gets a value from a form, and puts it into an URL. The variable `LINK`, which is the URL, is then supposed to be used for the second section to get a value from it.

Both the first and second sections work fine when they are separate, but do not work in the same HTML/PHP page.

For the first section, if I have `document.write(link);` then that will write the the link I want, but with both sections of the code on the webpage it no longer works.

I have no idea why this isn't working and have spent ages on it.

First section:

```php
<?php
    $player = $_POST['player'];
?>
<script>
  var player1 = "<?php echo $player; ?>";
  var link1 = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20content%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.team-des-fra.fr%2FCoM%2Fbf3.php%3Fp%3D";
  var link2 = "%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2F*%5B%40id%3D%22content%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B3%5D%2Fdiv%2Fspan'&format=json&callback=yqlcallback";
  var LINK = link1 + player1 + link2;
</script>
```

Second section:

```html
<script>
  var yqlcallback = function(data) {
    var results = data.query.results;
    document.write(results.span);
    var rating = results.span;
    rating = rating.slice(0, -1);
    if (rating > 30) {
      document.write("Hello");
    } else {
      document.write("Goodbye");
    }
  };
</script>
<script src=LINK></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this is not working"? Not working how? What do you see if you do `echo $_POST['player'];` ?

Comment: He's trying to make the script work. The link is generated in the first section. You can see what happened in the second section haha

Comment: The echo thing just puts the PHP value into the javascript so that the javascript value of player1 = the php value of $player

Answer (score 1):

This problem is with `<script src=LINK></script>`.

You can't put the LINK variable into HTML like that.

Try

HTML:

```
<script>
  // while you're at it, trying moving this stuff over to its own file
  var yqlcallback = function(data) {
    var results = data.query.results;
    document.write(results.span);
    var rating = results.span;
    rating = rating.slice(0, -1);
    if (rating > 30) {
        document.write("Hello");
    } else {
        document.write("Goodbye");
    }
  };
</script>
<script id="myscript"></script>
```

JS (put this in a script tag at the bottom of your page; or even better in its own file):

```
$('script').attr('src', LINK);
```

or without jQuery

```
document.getElementById('myscript').setAttribute('src', LINK);
```

You're new to web programming. You should get a good understanding of how JavaScript interacts with HTML, or you'll be running into these types of issues endlessly.

Comment: But when I put all the code into the file with that it still doesnt work

Comment: `Section 1 stuff is here                                                                                                            
section 2:
<script>
  var yqlcallback = function(data) {
    var results = data.query.results;
    document.write(results.span);
    var rating = results.span;
    rating = rating.slice(0, -1);
    if (rating > 30) {
        document.write("Hello");
    } else {
        document.write("Goodbye");
    }
  };
</script>
<script>
document.getElementById('myscript').setAttribute('src', link);
</script>
<script id="myscript"></script>

`

Comment: Give me a jsFiddle with your html and javascript, and I'll show you what you need to change to get it working. You shouldn't be building your app with piecemeal scripts all around your HTML file.

Comment: My jsfiddle link is: http://jsfiddle.net/geyp93xp/7/ Whenever i run it 12 comes up indicating that it has not worked

Comment: This works: jsfiddle.net/geyp93xp/8. You forgot to close a curly brace. Among other things: 1) The fact that 12 shows up has to do with your callback function and how it interacts with YQL, 2) Double check the URL you are generating, and 3) You really need to get a good understanding of programming before you jump in, or you'll have these problems constantly. Sit down with a good HTML/JS book for a day and it'll save you 3 days of work.

Comment: The url it generates is fine, I've checked that multiple times for multiple different players and when just displaying the data in the html thing and the link is fine